# Can't connect to MS SQL with pyodbc

Tags: python, microsoft, sql

I just spent hours trying to acomplish a simple task. I had python code that I used to run in windows, and it access a MS SQL db on a windows server 2008. I set up a ubuntu server and want to run this script in this server. after having installed pyodbc, freetds and a bunch of other packages I still can't connect to the DB. The windows connection string I was using was:

```
connectionString='DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=IP;DATABASE=Market;UID=usr;PWD=psw
```

after researching a lot I ended up with three connection files odbc.ini odbcinst.ini and freetds.conf and they look, respectively like this:

odbc.ini:

> [sqlserverdatasource] Driver = FreeTDS Description = ODBC connection
>   via FreeTDS Trace = No Servername = sqlserver Database = Market;

odbcinst.ini

> [FreeTDS] Description = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL) Driver =
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so Setup =
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so CPTimeout = CPReuse =
>   FileUsage = 1

freetds.conf

> [sqlserver]
>       host = 10.23.11.10;
>       port = 1433;
>       tds version = 5.0

Now i've been trying to test the connection with the following

```
tsql -S sqlserver
```

but i get the following error

> Error 20017 (severity 9):
>           Unexpected EOF from the server
>           OS error 115, "Operation now in progress" Error 20002 (severity 9):
>           Adaptive Server connection failed

I thought it would take a couple of minutes to make it work but I've wasted many hours. any help is deeply appreciated. thank you.

Comment: I had to specify the `PORT=1433` and `TDS_Version=7.2`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect to SQL Server from your linux machine I highly recommend you follow this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-python-simple-ubuntu-linux/

This uses another python driver pymssql which uses FreeTDS to connect to SQL Server. Let me know if this helps.

Best,

Meet

Comment: Hey, Meet. You may want to update the Ubuntu instructions [on this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt694094.aspx) since they no longer seem to work for SSL connections with Ubuntu 16.04 and the current version of pymssql. If you're interested, I have posted my own recipe for Ubuntu 16.04 and pymssql 2.1.3 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39395549/2144390).

Comment: True. I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Recently we developed and tested our SQL Server ODBC drivers with pyODBC 3.0.7 on Python 3.3 and connection was successful. All worked fine.

Try to download latest pyODBC driver https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc 
and this [SQL Server ODBC driver](https://www.devart.com/odbc/sqlserver/)
There is a connection strings example in documentation. You may use it.

Comment: I tried connecting from ubuntu to oracle db. Tested with pyodbc - it worked. Followed instruction on https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Oracle-from-RHEL-or-Centos

Answer (score 0):

I regularly connect to DBs using python.  My connection string is as follows:

> ConnectionString='DSN=MyDSN'

DSN stands for `Data source Name` and its details are are stored in the `odbc.ini` file in the form you use:

> [MyDSN]
>
> Driver = FreeTDS
>
> Description = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
>
> Trace = No
>
> Servername = sqlserver
>
> Database = Market
>
> USER = DBuser
>
> Password = yourpwd